# deriving Simpson rule

Tags: integration

I am bit concerned whether my notes from calculus 2 are incorrect or I am just stupid to not understand what I am doing..

I learned that Simpsons method being 
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{\Delta x}{6}\left[f(a) + f(b) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f\left(x_i\right) + 4\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_i + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]
\end{equation}

a= $(x_0)$: Start point

b = $(x_n)$: end point

$x_i$: intermediate points along x-axis.

$x_i + \frac{1}{2}$: point between $x_i$ and $x_i + 1$ in which $x_i < x_i+1$ along the x-axis.

But I cannot seem to be able to derive the formula, or even find a version that resembles that method.

I understand what the method does, generation a parabola from 3 points, and integrating over that area, but i cannot seem to understand how come that can become to this method?..

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Derivation help?

Comment: hmm..  but how come is the $2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f\left(x_i\right) $ appear?

Comment: What you have stated is the composite rule: the internal mesh points appear twice when you apply the simple rule to each interval. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson.27s_rule.

Comment: why $\frac{\Delta x}{6}$ ? and not $\frac{\Delta x}{3}$

Comment: There are some problems with the formula, like the $x_i$ should be defined  and $\frac 12$ should be half the gap between the successive $x_i$ - so these will confuse any attempt to prove it.

Comment: info added. Hopes it clarifies some of the issues..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch with the picture on the interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i+1}]$ (Assume that the points $x_i$ are evenly distributed in the interval $[a,b]$):

[image]

$$p_i(x)=f(x_{i-1})\frac{(x-x_i)(x-x_{i+1})}{(x_{i-1}-x_i)(x_{i-1}-x_{i+1})}+f(x_i)\frac{(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})}{(x_{i}-x_{i-1})(x_{i}-x_{i+1})}+f(x_{i+1})\frac{(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i})}{(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})}$$

Integrating $p_i(x)$ gives
$$\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_{i-1}}\,dx=\frac{\Delta x}{3}\left[f(x_{i-1})+4f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})\right]$$

Now if the points are from $x_0$ to $x_{2n}$, then you add the $n$ integrals together:
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_2}+...+\int_{x_{2n-2}}^{x_{2n}}=\frac{\Delta x}{3}\left[f(x_{0})+4f(x_1)+f(x_{2})+f(x_2)+4f(x_3)+f(x_4)+f(x_4)+4f(x_5)+f(x_6)+...+f(x_{2n-2})+4f(x_{2n-1})+f(x_{2n}))\right]\\
=\frac{\Delta x}{3}\left[f(x_0)+f(x_{2n})+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_{2k})+4\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{2k-1})\right]$$

I have a different form because I used $0,...,2n$.

**Edit**: There is another way to derive the two-subinterval integral without using the $p_i(x)$.

Let the interval be $[-h,h]$. We represent the curve using a polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$. Then the integral is
$$\int^h_{-h}ax^2+bx+c\,dx=2\int^h_0 ax^2+c\,dx=\frac{h}{3}(2ah^2+6c)$$

You can see that
$$f(-h)=ah^2-bh+c\\
f(0)=c\\
f(h)=ah^2+bh+c$$

Some algebraic manipulating gives you
$$f(-h)+4f(0)+f(h)=\frac{h}{3}(2ah^2+6c)$$

This can of course be shifted to get similar formulas on other subintervals. Then you can add them together to get the composite formula as above.

Comment: I am bit confused on how the parabola $p_i(x)$ is derived..

Comment: @sds: That is just a formula of Lagrange interpolation of degree $2$. Will this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: @sds: The basic idea is that you want to find a parabola (2nd degree polynomial) that passes through the three known points. There are many methods to find that, but Lagrange formula is simple to implement in this case. And all methods should give you a unique solution.

Comment: @sds: I added a simpler way to bypass the Lagrange interpolation $p_i(x)$.

Comment: How would you rearrange the last equation to the one I've stated above..

Comment: @sds: The last equation can be shifted to every interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i+1}]$. Then you add them as in my post. It is then equivalent as your equation, with your $n$ as my $2n$.

Comment: Could you explain how you integrate the function..

Comment: @sds: The first term is an even function, so it is twice of the integral on $[0,h]$. the second term $bx$ is an odd function, so $0$. The third term is again even, so twice.

Comment: I get it now..  :) A thing i was wondering about will the summation always assure to give either a odd or even number.. I mean otherwise the expression doesn't work.

Comment: @sds: I am not sure what you meant. But in your expression, $n$ has to be even. In other words, there has to be even number of subintervals to perform simpson's rule.

Comment: I just realized what you did :) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You should clarify that $x_i=\frac{x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}}{2}$.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher: It was assumed that the points $x_i$ are evenly distributed between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said you should clarify, since it wasn't stated. Anyone who does out that integral will find that they won't get the nice result without that piece of information. Some poor soul out there will be forever thankful :)

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher: Edited. :) Thanks!